# Copying layout to other project (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, copy

How can I copy the layout of a form to a form in another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the new project in the Visual Studio solution explorer and choose **Add**, **Existing Item**. Browse to the old project and select the form. A new copy of the form is generated in your current project. Then edit per @djechelon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the whole form into the other project, then edit the business logic code. Sounds straightforward, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If select then cut and paste from the form editor doesn't work for you, you could cut and paste the contents of the InitializeComponent class (in myform.designer.cs) from one form to another.

You'll actually need to copy most of the contents of the myform.designer.cs file - if you don't already understand how that works, then it's a good thing to get to grips with.  There's no magic in there, despite the warnings about not touching designer-generated code.